# Summing and rounding in XQuery

Tags: xml, math, xquery

I am attempting to sum and round values to 3 significant figures.

The rounding of the summed values should occur as follows:

```
527000.0              527000
11920.0                 11900
131900.0              131000
5960.0                   5960
14400.0                 14400
7200.0                   7200
17130.0                 17100
8565.0                   8560
```

The key thing I'm trying is rounding down (effectively truncating at 3rd sig fig)

32488.0 would become 32400.

I have tried utilising round-to-half-even($Input,-3) along with sum() and floor() to try achieve the desired result for variations in input data, but not having much luck.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the `math:` functions proposed for XQuery 3.0, calculate the number of relevant digits using the numbers logarithm and shift by dividing and multiplying with the proper power of ten:

```
for $number in (527000.0, 11920.0, 131900.0, 5960.0, 14400.0, 7200.0, 17130.0, 8565.0, 42.0, 0)
let $log := if ($number > 0) then floor(math:log10($number)) else 1
let $pow := math:pow(10, $log - 3)
return concat($number, ': ', floor($number div $pow) * $pow)
```

This will return the expected numbers:

```
527000: 527000
11920: 11920
131900: 131900
5960: 5960
14400: 14400
7200: 7200
17130: 17130
8565: 8565
42: 42
0: 0
```

If you're stuck with XQuery 1.0 or do not have access to the advanced mathematical functions, it gets more interesting (and ugly). What about some string manipulation?

```
for $number in (527000.0, 11920.0, 131900.0, 5960.0, 14400.0, 7200.0, 17130.0, 8565.0, 42.0, 0)
let $string := xs:string($number)
let $length := string-length($string)
return concat($number, ': ', substring($string, 1, 3), string-join(for $i in 4 to $length return '0'))
```

You could of course convert back to numbers again. I'm not sure whether there might be a more elegant way; and this code needs to be extended if it should support non-natural or non-positive numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck with XQuery 1.0, so the ugly approach might have to be adopted. Thanks for your reply, I'll have a look into this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves it

```
let $String := xs:string($XAMT)
let $Length := string-length($String)
let $SubString := substring($String, 1, 3)
let $TrailingZeros := for $i in 4 to $Length -2 return '0'


let $Result := concat($SubString, string-join(($TrailingZeros),''))



return $Result
```